# Slow upload speed in aws deploy push command

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli, aws-code-deploy

I am trying to use AWS CodeDeploy. I use `aws deploy push --debug` command. The file to be uploaded is around 250 KB. But upload doesn't finish. Following is the logs displayed.

```
2017-10-27 11:11:40,601 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - CanonicalRequest:
PUT
/frontend-deployer/business-services-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-classes.jar
partNumber=39&uploadId=.olvaJkxreDZf1ObaHCMtHmkQ5DFE.uZ9Om0sxZB08YG3tqRWBxmGLTFWSYQaj9mHl26LPJk..Stv_vPB5NMaV.zAqsYX6fZz_S3.uN5J4FlxHZFXoeTkMiBSYQB2C.g
content-md5:EDXgvJ8Tt5tHYZ6Nkh7epg==
host:s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
x-amz-content-sha256:UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
x-amz-date:20171027T081140Z

content-md5;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD
...
2017-10-27 11:12:12,035 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Sending http request: <PreparedRequest [PUT]>
2017-10-27 11:12:12,035 - MainThread - botocore.awsrequest - DEBUG - Waiting for 100 Continue response.
2017-10-27 11:12:12,189 - MainThread - botocore.awsrequest - DEBUG - 100 Continue response seen, now sending request body.
```

Even though the file is fairly small (250 KB), upload doesn't finish.

On the other hand, upload via `aws s3 cp` command lasts 1 second.

How can I increase the upload speed in `aws deploy push` command?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?